# Let $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $A$ is open, prove that $A\cap\overline{B}\neq\emptyset\Rightarrow A\cap B\neq\emptyset$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $A,B\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ where $A$ is open, prove that $A\cap\overline{B}\neq\emptyset\Rightarrow A\cap B\neq\emptyset$

For this I rather prove $A\cap B=\emptyset\Rightarrow A\cap\overline{B}=\emptyset$ which seems easier

Here I go:

$A\cap\overline{B}$ is non empty then $\exists x_{0}\in A,\: x_{0}\in\overline{B}$

As $x_{0}\in\overline{B}=B\cup B'$ then $x_{0}\in B$ or $x_{0}\in B'$

If $x_{0}\in B'\Rightarrow\exists\left(b_{n}\right)\subset B:b_{n}\to x_{0}\left(b_{n}\neq x_{0}\right)\iff\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists n_{0}:n\geq n_{0}\Rightarrow0<\|b_{n}-x_{0}\|<\varepsilon$

But as $A$ is open, $A=A^{o}$ so $x_{0}\in A^{o}$ and therefore any time $x_{n}\to x_{0},\exists n_{0}:n\geq n_{0},x_{n}\in A$

Taking $x_{n}=b_{n}$ then $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$

Is this correct? Or is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer works, but you don't have to assume that you show the negation of the implication, because if you look at your proof you'll find that it's actually direct, just delete "assume" and "contradiction" :)

It is often worth looking again at a proof done "by contradiction" and sometimes you find that it's actually a direct one or you can give a direct one along the same lines!

Comment: haha Thanks!! I'm a new student so there's lots to learn! Thanks for the advice and answer!

Answer (score 1):

If $B \cap A = \emptyset$, then $B \subset \complement A$, a closed set. Then $\overline{B} \subset \complement A$, or $A \cap \overline{B} = \emptyset$.

Comment: Good point!! I will write that down too thanks!!